# EXCEL- Sum, data displayed through index

Tags: excel

i'm using following formula to retrieve values from another sheet

`=IF(ISERROR((INDEX(Airline!$B$1:$F$12,SMALL(IF(Airline!$C$5:$C$12=$F$3,ROW(Airline!$C$5:$C$12)),ROW(1:1)),4))),"",INDEX(Airline!$B$1:$F$12,SMALL(IF(Airline!$C$5:$C$12=$F$3,ROW(Airline!$C$5:$C$12)),ROW(1:1)),4))&""`

my question is how to SUM retrieved values. Simple SUM `=sum(c5:c15)` is not working.

Comment: array formula will probably solve it.  Press ctrl-shift-enter instead of just enter

Comment: yes i did, but still having same problem. values retrieved through this formula cant even be formatted.

Comment: First off your "simple sum" is not how `SUM` works.  I'd suggest first checking the documentation for SUM.

Comment: i just need to sum up output values could you please help

Comment: I've changed the formula and result is promising except i'm now returning value #NUM! in an empty cell. following is my formula please elaborate =(INDEX(Airline!$B$5:$F$12,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($F$3,Airline!$C$5:$C$12),ROW(Airline!$B$5:$F$12)-MIN(ROW(Airline!$B$5:$F$12))+1),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)))

Answer (score 0):

i've found solution. here it is
=IFERROR(INDEX(Airline!$B$5:$F$12,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($F$3,Airline!$C$5:$C$12),ROW(Airline!$B$5:$F$12)-MIN(ROW(Airline!$B$5:$F$12))+1),ROW(D1)),COLUMN(D1)),"")